# How to mix two array in such a way that they merge simoultaneously

Tags: php

These are all associative arrays.
$arr1 and $arr2 looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2
        [model] => nike
        [manufacturer_id] => 2147483647
        [weight_class] => 2222222

    )
)

for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
                $data[$i] .= $arr1[$i]. $arr2[$i]; 
            }
```

Comment: Can't see array2. Please add more info or elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Consider array2 is also similar 2 array1

Comment: Post the possible inputs along with the expected output

Comment: i want to merge both arrays with same index for instance in this case the index 0 of data array will have all the parameters of arr1 and arr2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) as in below example .

```
$array1 = array("id1" => "value1");

$array2 = array("id2" => "value2", "id3" => "value3", "id4" => "value4");

$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2/*, $arrayN, $arrayN*/);
$array4 = $array1 + $array2;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array3);
var_dump($array4);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: array merge appends one array after the other but i want simultaneously

Comment: can you please post your two array and also the output(array) that you want  ??